# Setup a mock for a method using Expression

Tags: c#, linq, moq

I'm trying to setup a mocked return value for a method. I know the classic way of doing it, but I want to do it by creating Expression objects explicitly. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MoqTest
{
    public interface IBlah
    {
        string DoStuff(string x);
    }

    public class SomeProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mock<IBlah> m = new Mock<IBlah>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            //I want to do the equivalent of this:
            //m.Setup(a => a.DoStuff(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("mocked!");

            var method = typeof(IBlah).GetMethod("DoStuff", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            ParameterExpression parameterForDoStuff = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
            ParameterExpression thisParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBlah), "someIBlahInstance");
            MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(thisParameter, method, new[] { parameterForDoStuff });
            Expression<Func<IBlah, string>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<IBlah, string>>(methodCall, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterForDoStuff });
            //above line fails: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: ParameterExpression of type 'System.String' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'MoqTest.IBlah'

            m.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns("mocked!");

            Assert.AreEqual("mocked!", m.Object.DoStuff(string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm confused when it comes to the lambdaExpression - should I be creating one that represents a `Func<string,string>` (for the IBlah.DoStuff method), or should I be creating a `Func<IBlah,string>` (representing the lambda parameter for the Mock.Setup method)? I put the equivalent setup that I want to do in a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating a `Expression<Func<IBlah, string>>` representing the expression parameter for the `Mock.Setup` method.

Which means that there should only be one parameter expression.

Also, in building the desired expression, `It.IsAny<T>()` is a generic static method call on the static class `Moq.It`.

Review the comments to see how that static call is built into the expression using reflection.

```
[TestClass]
public class MoqExpressionTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Build_Moq_Expression() {
        //Arrange
        //I want to do the equivalent of this:
        //m.Setup(a => a.DoStuff(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("mocked!");
        var doStuff = typeof(IBlah).GetMethod("DoStuff", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        var isAnyOfString = typeof(It).GetMethod("IsAny").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

        // IBlah x =>
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBlah), "x");
        // It.IsAny<string>()            
        var arg = Expression.Call(isAnyOfString);
        // IBlah x => x.DoStuff(It.IsAny<string>())           
        MethodCallExpression body = Expression.Call(parameter, doStuff, new[] { arg });
        //Func<IBlah, string> = IBlah x => x.DoStuff(It.IsAny<string>())
        Expression<Func<IBlah, string>> expression = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<IBlah, string>>(body, parameter);

        var expected = "mocked!";
        Mock<IBlah> m = new Mock<IBlah>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        m.Setup(expression).Returns(expected);
        var subject = m.Object;

        //Act
        var actual = subject.DoStuff(string.Empty);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public interface IBlah {
        string DoStuff(string x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you can no use a string parameter for It.IsAny, need use MethodCallExpression
2. for the lambdaExpression Expression second parameter should be thisParameter.

   ```
   public class SomeProgram
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Mock<IBlah> m = new Mock<IBlah>(MockBehavior.Strict);

           //I want to do the equivalent of this:
           //m.Setup(a => a.DoStuff(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("mocked!");

           var method = typeof(IBlah).GetMethod("DoStuff", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
           MethodInfo genericIsAnyMethodInfo =
               typeof(It).GetMethods().Single(e => e.Name == "IsAny").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
           MethodCallExpression parameterForDoStuff = Expression.Call(genericIsAnyMethodInfo);
           //ParameterExpression parameterForDoStuff = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
           ParameterExpression thisParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBlah), "someIBlahInstance");
           MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(thisParameter, method, new[] { parameterForDoStuff });
           Expression<Func<IBlah, string>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<IBlah, string>>(methodCall, thisParameter);
           //above line fails: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: ParameterExpression of type 'System.String' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'MoqTest.IBlah'

           m.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns("mocked!");

           Assert.AreEqual("mocked!", m.Object.DoStuff(string.Empty));
       }
   }
   ```